# (iphone) anyone had a success using boost with xcode4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, boost, linker

I have been using cross compiled boost static library(system,thread) with ios sdk 4.1 just fine.
(cross compiling part was hell of a job and i don't recall how i 've done that Meh!)

I updated to xcode4 and it fails to link with error msg:
Bad codegen, pointer diff in boost::detail....

I saw that some people try to manipulate "Symbols Hidden by Default" and similar option to disable the warning.

I strongly suspect that the error has to be dealt with proper way.(I saw other postings that people had success compiling it with the options changed but they reported frequent crashing)

I wonder anyone has moved to xcode4 with boost successfully.

Please share how you have done if you did.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: [XCode 3.2.6 and 4 linker errors ld:bad codegen, pointer diff in ... to global weak symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353779/xcode-3-2-6-and-4-linker-errors-ldbad-codegen-pointer-diff-in-to-global-wea/6626525#6626525)