# Xcode4: "bad codegen, pointer diff" linker error again

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker

This question is related to this: ["bad codegen, pointer diff" linker error with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285844/bad-codegen-pointer-diff-linker-error-with-xcode-4) and ["bad codegen, pointer diff in boost" error in 32-bit build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087292/bad-codegen-pointer-diff-in-boost-error-in-32-bit-build) and [XCode 3.2.6 and 4 linker errors ld:bad codegen, pointer diff in ... to global weak symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353779/xcode-3-2-6-and-4-linker-errors-ldbad-codegen-pointer-diff-in-to-global-wea)

I am currently upgrading all my projects to Xcode4 and I am experiencing some weirdness.- The above error only occurs if I build a universal binary or the 32-bit version. If I stick to 64 bit only, things work fine. I am building a custom static library myself, where right now I don't use any visibility settings (i.e. **attribute** ((visibility ("default")))) in that code. If I link that library and try to build the project, the exact error is:

> ld: bad codegen, pointer diff in Motor::Core::DefaultStoragePolicy::DefaultStoragePolicy(myWindowContent* const&)to global weak symbol Motor::Core::NullPointerException::~NullPointerException()for architecture i386

It is located in my SmartPtr class which can throw a NullPointerException (just derives from std::exception). If I explicitly set the visibility of the NullPointerException class to hidden, things compile fine, but hiding an exception can't be good! I tried the following compilers: GCC 4.2, LLVM-GCC 4.2 and LLVM 2.1 all with the same problem. Setting **Symbols Hidden By Default** to **yes** in he project/target settings didn't work (and is also not what I want). So how can I solve this without hiding my exceptions (which is nonsense). Do I have to live with it, is it a bug? Looking forward to you ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the error, I had **Inline Methods Hidden** set to **yes** in my application while it was set to no when building my static library. so if you encounter the same problem, make sure that you have **Inline Methods Hidden** set to **No**. Now my code also works with Symbols Hidden By Default set to no, which is what I want!

Still it is a mystery to me why the error only shows up in 32-bit build.