# How to understand LLVM Clang link error message? Any indication?

Tags: iphone, llvm, clang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“bad codegen, pointer diff” linker error with Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285844/bad-codegen-pointer-diff-linker-error-with-xcode-4)

Using LLVM 3.0 to compile a large project and get the following link error message, how can I understand? How to analysis? Which part is wrong? Thanks.

```
ld: bad codegen, pointer diff in ___cxx_global_var_init607 to global weak symbol
__ZN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS_16exception_detail10clone_baseEED1Ev for architecture i386 Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285844/bad-codegen-pointer-diff-linker-error-with-xcode-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087292/bad-codegen-pointer-diff-in-boost-error-in-32-bit-build

Comment: Agreed. It's a duplicate as wilx says above.